# Cannot understand the difference between static and non-static variables in Java. Can anyone help please?

Tags: java

In java, i am trying to understand the difference between static and non-static objects and variables like this.

**Code with static object:**

package abc;

public class StaticUsage {

```
public static StaticUsage propfile;

public static void main(String[] args) {

    checkifPropertiesFileisnull();
    checkifPropertiesFileisnull();
    checkifPropertiesFileisnotnull();
    /*stu.checkifPropertiesFileisnull();*/
}

private static void checkifPropertiesFileisnotnull() {
    if(propfile==null) {
        System.out.println("Propfile is " + propfile);
        propfile = new StaticUsage();
    }
    else {
        System.out.println("Propfile value is " + propfile);
    }
}


private static void checkifPropertiesFileisnull() {
    if(propfile==null) {
        System.out.println("Propfile is " + propfile);
        propfile = new StaticUsage();
    }
    else {
        System.out.println("Propfile value is " + propfile);
    }

}
```

}

**Code with non-static object:**

package abc;

public class StaticUsage {

```
public StaticUsage propfile;

public static void main(String[] args) {

    StaticUsage stu = new StaticUsage();
    stu.checkifPropertiesFileisnull();
    stu.checkifPropertiesFileisnull();
    stu.checkifPropertiesFileisnotnull();
    /*stu.checkifPropertiesFileisnull();*/
}

private void checkifPropertiesFileisnotnull() {
    if(propfile==null) {
        System.out.println("Propfile is " + propfile);
        propfile = new StaticUsage();
    }
    else {
        System.out.println("Propfile value is " + propfile);
    }
}


private void checkifPropertiesFileisnull() {
    if(propfile==null) {
        System.out.println("Propfile is " + propfile);
        propfile = new StaticUsage();
    }
    else {
        System.out.println("Propfile value is " + propfile);
    }

}
```

}

However, in both cases i am getting output as the below:

Propfile is null
Propfile value is abc.StaticUsage@15db9742
Propfile value is abc.StaticUsage@15db9742

I have heard that for static objects, it is shared throughout the instance of the class. So, i am getting the value for the first time as null, and the rest not null. But, then why for non-static objects, i am getting the same value? The value for the first method call should go to heap according to me, and then at the time of calling the second method, it should be again showing as null.

Can anyone please clear me the confusion?

Comment: I haven't read the question since it's humongous, but I suggest a following Java Tutorial rather than posting trivial questions here.

Comment: It will be great, if you site an example program, so that i can clear myself the difference between static and non-static objects.

Comment: No...its ok...thanks...now its clear to me...i was calling the same object in non-static objects. So, the same value was printing as that of static methods. But, now it's clear. I tried with putting different objects and it is now clear. that static variables are throughout the class, but instance variables belon to one particular object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Static properties belong to the Class whereas instance variables belong to the particular object instance. You should take a read through this: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/classvars.html